# How to activate Windows 10 in C# winform application

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created an application to get the OEM key and then activate Windows with that key. I can get the key from

```
ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM SoftwareLicensingService");
```

But how can I activate Windows with that key? I can do that with Powershell as below:

```
$service = get-wmiObject -query 'select * from SoftwareLicensingService'
if($key = $service.OA3xOriginalProductKey){
    Write-Host 'Activating using product Key:' $service.OA3xOriginalProductKey
    $service.InstallProductKey($key)
}else{
    Write-Host 'Key not found. Please contact IT for more information'
}
pause
```

Comment: [How to Call a WMI Class Method by Using System.Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/develop/core/clients/programming/how-to-call-a-wmi-class-method-by-using-system.management?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: [InstallProductKey method of the SoftwareLicensingService class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/sppwmi/installproductkey-softwarelicensingservice?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call methods of a WMI object by using [InvokeMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobject.invokemethod?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) of the [ManagementObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobject?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). Here you are interested to invoke the [InstallProductKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/sppwmi/installproductkey-softwarelicensingservice?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method of [SoftwareLicensingService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/sppwmi/softwarelicensingservice?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

For example:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
    "SELECT * FROM SoftwareLicensingServissce");
var obj = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().First();
var inParams = obj.GetMethodParameters("InstallProductKey");
inParams["ProductKey"] = obj["OA3xOriginalProductKey"];
var outParams = obj.InvokeMethod("InstallProductKey", inParams, null);
MessageBox.Show(((PropertyData)outParams["ReturnValue"])?.Value?.ToString());
```

To run the example, make sure you "Run as Administrator".

Comment: The code is just an example and you may want to add some null checking and also instead of `obj["OA3xOriginalProductKey"]` you may want to use a license key. There are also a few other method you may want to involve in the process. You can take a look at [this repository](https://github.com/vmsh0/JustActivateWindows/blob/master/jaw/Operations/LicensingHelper.cs) for more examples.

Comment: Thanks for your help!. Seems like didn't work in my environment! Received invalid parameters error

Comment: @HuTran Run Visual Studio as Administrator

Comment: it works with the Administrator right. thanks!